# Cannot parse JSON containing list of objects with python json library

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a simple python (version 3.10.2) script that uses the `requests` library to make a REST call to an API. The call returns a list of objects. I find that the `json.loads()` function will not parse the JSON returned in the response. It gives me the following error:

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list`

Oddly, the `json.dumps()` function can successfully format the same data.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

def get_groups(url):
  # TODO SSL/TLS turned OFF (verify=False)
  response = requests.get(url + "/groups", verify=False)

  print("status code:", response.status_code)
  print("JSON:\n")
  print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))

  json.loads(response.json())
```

Here is an example what `json.dumps()` is outputting:

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "web_url": "https://<URL redacted>/groups/test",
    "name": "test",
    "path": "test",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "public",
    "share_with_group_lock": false,
    "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
    "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
    "project_creation_level": "developer",
    "auto_devops_enabled": null,
    "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
    "emails_disabled": null,
    "mentions_disabled": null,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "default_branch_protection": 2,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "request_access_enabled": true,
    "full_name": "test",
    "full_path": "test",
    "created_at": "2021-08-03T15:41:34.523Z",
    "parent_id": null,
    "ldap_cn": null,
    "ldap_access": null
  }
]
```

I have seen lots of postings about this and every one mentions using `json.loads()` to parse the JSON data. Not sure why it works for them, but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: Because your response is already parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out by [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl), in this case the HTTP/REST response object returns the JSON data already parsed. For some reason I missed that. I don't need to to use the `json` library.